# Images are repeated even if I upload diff images everytime. I think logic is not correct in uploadMultipleImages()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

I am displaying images as I upload them and every time I upload diff images, images in the  fileArray are repeated and shows the same images every time.
 Even if I add a diff no of images, the same images are shown. Please check the logic in function uploadMultipleFiles.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './MultipleImageUpload.css';

export default class MultipleImageUploadComponent extends Component {
   fileObj = [];
   fileArray = [];

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        file: [null],
    };
    this.uploadMultipleFiles = this.uploadMultipleFiles.bind(this);
    this.uploadFiles = this.uploadFiles.bind(this);
}

uploadMultipleFiles(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ fileObj: [] });
    this.fileObj.push(e.target.files);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.fileObj[0].length; ++i) {
        this.fileArray.push(URL.createObjectURL(this.fileObj[0][i]));
    }
    this.setState({ file: this.fileArray });
}

uploadFiles(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.file);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className='MultipleImageComponent'>
            <form>
                <div className='form-group multi-preview'>
                    {(this.fileArray || []).map(url => (
                        <img src={url} alt='...' />
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div className='form-group'>
                    <input
                        type='file'
                        className='form-control'
                        onChange={this.uploadMultipleFiles}
                        multiple
                    />
                </div>
                <button
                    type='button'
                    className='btn btn-danger btn-block'
                    onClick={this.uploadFiles}
                >
                    Upload Multiple Images
                </button>
            </form>
            </div>
         );
      }
      }
```

Comment: I tried your code and eveything works fine, i dont see the images getting repeated. Its displayed only once.

Trying putting your code in CodeSandbox and see if it works as you are expecting,

Comment: Try to upload images and then click the upload button and then again upload images. You'll see the same images been uploaded that were uploaded before.